# Redirect after only signup and login failure in devise rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

My login and signup forms are on home/index.html.erb. I want that when any of them fail error should show on index.html.erb . Now it redirect to devise views. 
How can I do that?

Note : I want this only for signup and login. Password Forgot scenario will remain `devise` default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do like this:

create class on lib folder and overwrite devise failure

```
class CustomFailure < Devise::FailureApp
  def redirect_url
     #your path
  end

  def respond
    if http_auth?
     http_auth
   else
     redirect
   end
 end
```

end

And put this config/initializers/devise.rb

```
  config.warden do |manager|
    manager.failure_app = CustomFailure
  end
```

One more thing you have to auto load lib file like:

```
config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')
```

put this line at config/application.rb

I hope that will work

EDITED

```
 def redirect_url

    if request.referrer.include? new_user_session_path.split("/").last
       #your path
    else
       new_user_session_path
    end
 end
```

Comment: Is it effect both signup and login?

Comment: If I want only for signup and login. Not for every page

Comment: @Ansar give the answer what haseeb is asking for ?

Comment: @Bharatsoni Looking solution need to run code cant say at the moment, if you have solution then addd in your answer

Comment: @haseeb, you can try like this:  check request.referrer.include? new_user_session_path.split("/").last then move to particular path else other path

Comment: @haseeb try my solution, I have added in my answer hope that will work for you

Comment: Thanks @Ansar . Just want to know where I put this code?

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom_failure.rb in your lib directory, with:

```
class CustomFailure < Devise::FailureApp
  def redirect_url
    your_path
  end

  def respond
    if http_auth?
      http_auth
    else
      redirect
    end
  end
end
```

In you Devise initializer, include:

```
config.warden do |manager|
    manager.failure_app = CustomFailure
  end
```

Make sure Rails is loadin your lib files, in your application.rb :

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

Don't forget to restart your server from root of your application.

I don't think there's an easier way to do this. Good luck.

Comment: Is it effect both signup and login?

Comment: If I want only for signup and login. Not for every page?